# Python Sort a List containing sets

Tags: python, list, sorting

Any idea how to sort a list that contains elements of type set ?
This is the code I'm using:

```
 sorted_by_second = sorted(result_list, key=lambda set: set[1])
```

Example of how my result_list looks like:

```
[['past due', '32.86691794423967'], ['code', '23.24240338748313'], ['why:customer','27.65754595407057']]
```

I would like to sort the list by descending order according to the 2nd element in each tupple of the list elements.
The sorted list result should look like

```
 [['past due', '32.86691794423967'], ['why:customer','27.65754595407057'], ['code', '23.24240338748313']]
```

Comment: You *can't* have sets because sets are unordered, so `set[1]` is meaningless.

Comment: Note that the second element is a string, so will sort lexicographically - you need to convert to `float` if you want numerical sorting.

Comment: @user4045430 If your question is answered, close the question

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) to map the second element from a string to a number. This will allow `sorted` to sort by numbers. If you don't use `float`, `sorted` will sort the second element as strings.

```
sorted(result_list, key=lambda x: float(x[1]), reverse=True)
```

Result:

```
[['past due', '32.86691794423967'],
 ['why:customer', '27.65754595407057'],
 ['code', '23.24240338748313']]
```

Hint: Don't use `set` as a name since [it is a built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set).

Answer (score -1):

sortedlst contain the descending sorted elements by second element

```
lst=[['past due', '32.86691794423967'], ['code', '23.24240338748313'], ['why:customer','27.436']]

sortedlst=sorted(lst,key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)
print sortedlst
```